# Proof explanation of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n+k)(n-k) = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(4n-1), n \geq 1$

Tags: analysis, induction, proof-explanation

I don't understand the proof of

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n+k)(n-k) = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(4n-1), n \geq 1$$

via induction.

$$\text{Base case}:  n=1 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^0(1+k)(1-k)=1=\frac{1}{6}(1+1)(4-1) = \frac{6}{6}$$

$$\text{Inductive step:} \sum_{k=0}^n (n+1+k)(n+1-k) = \sum_{k=0}^n[(n+k)(n-k)+(n-k)+(n+k)+1]$$

$$= \sum_{k=0}^n (n+k)(n-k)+\sum_{k=0}^n1+2n \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n1$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n+k)(n-k)+(n+n)(n-n)+(n+1)+2n\cdot(n+1)$$

$$= \text{(IH)} \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(4n-1)+(n+1)+2n(n+1)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6} (n+1)(n(4n-1)+6+12n)$$

$$= \frac{1}{6}(n+1) (4n^2+11n+6)$$

$$= \frac{1}{6}(4n+3)(n+2)$$

I don't understand the first 3 lines of the inductive step.

Why do we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n[(n+k)(n-k)+(n-k)+(n+k)+1]$$

and

$$= \sum_{k=0}^n (n+k)(n-k)+\sum_{k=0}^n1+2n \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n1$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n+k)(n-k)+(n+n)(n-n)+(n+1)+2n\cdot(n+1)$$

Comment: Do you agree that $\left(a+1\right)\left(b+1\right)=ab+b+a+1$? Apply that on $a=n+k$ and $b=n-k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left[(n+1+k)(n+1-k)\right] = \sum_{k=0}^n\left[(n+k)(n-k)+(n-k)+(n+k)+1\right]$$

we are using that

$$(n+1+k)(n+1-k)=((n+k)+1)((n-k)-1)=$$

$$=(n+k)(n-k)+(n-k)+(n+k)+1$$

and then since $(n+k)+(n-k)=2n$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\left[(n+k)(n-k)+(n-k)+(n+k)+1\right]=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n \left[(n+k)(n-k)\right]+$$

$$+\sum_{k=0}^n 2n+$$

$$+\sum_{k=0}^n 1$$

and for the last step, we have used that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left[(n+k)(n-k)\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[(n+k)(n-k)\right]+(n+n)(n-n)$$

Comment: How the hell do you type and think so fast? Thank you!

Comment: @RamanujanTaylor You are welcome! Bye :)